# Openfire gloox XEP-0013

Tags: gloox

I am trying to implement *XEP-0013* using *Openfire* and the *gloox* lib. In my XMPP client, I am calling the `checkSupport()` API through an`gloox::FlexibleOffline` object in an `OnConnect()` event.
`handleFlexibleOfflineSupport` says it is supported, but I still receive offline message after presence is sent as online after login. `fetchMessages()` doesn't provide the messages as well. The message count that is returned is *0*.

Should I configure anything on Openfire or should I change API calls?